# The effect of channel error on the determinant of transmitted matrix

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices, determinant, coding-theory

Assume the following matrix

$$
E:=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 e_1  & e_2  & \cdots  &  e_{p-1}  & e_{p}\\
 e_{p+1}  & e_{p+2}  & \cdots  &  e_{2p-1}  & e_{2p}  \\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots  &  \vdots &\vdots    \\
 e_{p^2-p+1}  &  e_{p^2-p+2}  &   \cdots  &  e_{p^2-1}  & e_{p^2}
\end{array}
\right)_{p\times p}=(e_{i})\in {\Bbb{R}}^{p \times p}\, .
$$
Let the determinant of  the matrix $E$ is a number like $m$, and suppose $l_i$, $1\leq i \leq p^2$, is the number of decimal 
digits in the $i$th entry of the matrix $E$. Imagine, we are as a sender in a communication system and we want to send the entries 
of the matrix $E$, through a noisy channel. Suppose the channel error probability per decimal symbol is $q$. 
We denote the received matrix $E$, by $\widehat{E}$. Consider, the entries 
of the matrix $\widehat{E}$, are received with $k$ errors, where $2\leq k \leq p^2$. I mean, we have at least two errors. 
 Now, my question it is, with which probability, the determinant of the received matrix $\widehat{E}$ is
equal the $m$, when $k$ entries of the matrix $\widehat{E}$, are received with errors. Notice that, $k$ errors can be 
happen in the ${{p^2}\choose{k}}=\frac{p^2!}{k!\, (p^2-k)!}$ cases in the matrix $\widehat{E}$.

I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: no offense intended but why would you be interested in a problem like this?...

Comment: This question is one of the open problems in the decoding process in a new class of coding theory called Fibonacci coding. For more details, please see the following article: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2005.12.054

Comment: I don't have access to the paper but it looks at least 10 years old, so this isn't "new". I'm also put off by the claim : "For the simplest case the correct ability of the method is equal 93.33% which exceeds essentially all well-known correcting codes"...what exactly is "correct ability"? From what I can tell, this is a (somewhat convoluted) nonlinear coding scheme and the solution is likely to be complicated..all singular matrices will have zero determinant for example and likely to stay so with many errors, how would you get any information out of these?

Comment: @unknown  you right. The article that i mentioned, is not suitable for learning the fibonacci coding. One of the best source to familiar with code rate and error-correcting capability of Fibonacci coding is the last chapter of the following thesis
https://www.docdroid.net/EZSVY8i/fibonacci-coding.pdf.html

Comment: The encoding process looks really convoluted and even if we ignore the implementation complexity (which I think will be huge), I still don't see the advantage. If you believe there's a coding advantage, you should run some simulations to verify. Use BSC channel for starters. That might be a lot easier than deriving analytic expressions for error rates. It is also a perfectly acceptable way to show coding advantage if it can be duplicated.